# Template metaprogram to find similar consecutive typenames

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I am new to template meta programming and was trying to create a program that would find if a parameter pack has consecutive same type names. For example `<int, int>`, `<int, char, char>` would return true and `<int,char>` and `<int, char, int>` would not.

I managed to write this piece of code but it seems to be comparing each value of parameter pack with itself. I am just looking for a way to iterate through the values of parameter pack to compare with it's consecutive element.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct sameTypename{
    enum {value = false};
};

template<typename T>
struct sameTypename<T, T>{
    enum {value = true};
};

template <typename T, typename ...args>
struct consTypename{
    enum {value = (sameTypename<consTypename<args...>, consTypename<args...>>::value)};
};

template <typename T>
struct consTypename<T, T>{
    enum {value = true};
};

template <typename T>
struct consTypename<T>{
    enum {value = false};
};
```

Comment: What do you think `sameTypename<consTypename<args...>, consTypename<args...>>::value` is going to do?

Comment: You seem to have missed your examples "For example , would return true and and would not."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...P> struct has_adjacent_same_types : std::false_type {};
template <typename A, typename B, typename ...P> struct has_adjacent_same_types<A, B, P...>
    : std::bool_constant<std::is_same_v<A,B> || has_adjacent_same_types<B, P...>::value> {};
```

I used `: std::false_type {};` and `: std::bool_constant<X> {};` instead of
`{enum{value = false};};` and `{enum{value = X};};` respectively, but that's simply a matter of preference.

---

Some of the features I used are from C++17. If you're using an older version, note that:

> `std::bool_constant` and `std::is_same_v` are available only starting from C++17 (but that you can use `std::integral_constant` and `std::is_same<>::value` before).
>
> (c) @max66

Comment: Nice. But the OP tagged only C++; we don't know if he can use C++17; we can say only that he can use at least C++11 because he use variadic templates. I suggest to signal that `std::bool_constant` and `std::is_same_v` are available only starting from C++17 (but that you can use `std::integral_constant` and `std::is_same<>::value` before).

Comment: I didn't mention the version of C++ because I wasn't bounded by it. This did the trick and I learned how to deal with parameter packs. I am using enum to get the values and my own definition of sameType instead of is_same_v. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the HolyBlackCat's solution.

```
template <typename ...>
struct has_adjacent_same_types : public std::false_type
 { };

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct has_adjacent_same_types<T0, T0, Ts...> : public std::true_type
 { };

template <typename T0, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct has_adjacent_same_types<T0, T1, Ts...>
   : public has_adjacent_same_types<T1, Ts...>
 { };
```

Two simpler specializations instead of only one, more complex.

Substantially is the same things (I suppose) but I find it a little clear to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

I propose also a completely different solution that uses template folding (so only C++17 or newer, unfortunately) instead of template recursion.

```
template <typename...>
struct sae_helper;

template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Us>
struct sae_helper<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Us...>>
   : public std::bool_constant<(std::is_same_v<Ts, Us> || ...)>
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct some_adjacent_equal
   : public sae_helper<std::tuple<void, Ts...>, std::tuple<Ts..., void>>
 { };
```

If `void` is a possible type in the list of type to check, calling `sae_helper` from `some_adjacent_equal` instead of `void` must be used a different type, obviously.

I suppose that this solution is preferable, over a recursive one, when the list of types is very long because avoid compilers template-recursion limits.

If you can use C++14, you can use a `constexpr` function instead of template folding (and a tag-type instead of void) as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Us>
constexpr bool sae_helper (std::tuple<Ts...> const &,
                           std::tuple<Us...> const &)
 {
   using unused = bool[];

   bool ret { false };

   (void)unused { true, ret |= std::is_same<Ts, Us>::value... };

   return ret;
 }

struct no_type
 { };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct some_adjacent_equal
   : public std::integral_constant<bool, sae_helper(std::tuple<no_type, Ts...>{},
                                                    std::tuple<Ts..., no_type>{})>
 { };
```

but, this way, you loose short-circuiting in or evaluation.